# How can I make a point cloud shared?

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I'm working on `kinect V2` and its grabber to run it. I encountered some problems wanting to write the cloud information on `pcd`. Look at this code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{ 
    boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer(new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer("Point Cloud Viewer")); 
    viewer->registerKeyboardCallback(&keyboard_callback, "keyboard"); 
    viewer->registerMouseCallback(&mouse_callback, "mouse"); 

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr cloud; 
    boost::function<void(const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr&)> function = 
            [&cloud](const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr &ptr){ 
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex); 
            cloud = ptr; 
    }; 

    pcl::Grabber* grabber = new pcl::Kinect2Grabber(); 

    boost::signals2::connection connection = grabber->registerCallback(function); 

    grabber->start(); 

    while (!viewer->wasStopped()){ 
            viewer->spinOnce(); 

            if (cloud){ 
                    if (!viewer->updatePointCloud(cloud, "cloud")){ 
                            viewer->addPointCloud(cloud, "cloud"); 
                            viewer->resetCameraViewpoint("cloud"); 
                    } 
            } 

            if (GetKeyState(VK_ESCAPE) < 0){ 
                    break; 
            } 
    } 

    grabber->stop(); 

    return 0; 
}
```

The cloud pointer for the boost function must be a `const` (I don't know for sure). Hence I can't share it with `cloud.makeShared()` function and `cloud->makeShared()` is aborted by throwing some exceptions. I tried also to copy it to regular cloud but did not work. Can you help me how can I write this cloud on a `pcd` file?

Comment: I compliment you on finding as many things as possible that "PCL" could possibly mean.

Comment: What? Do you mean the name space pcl (Point cloud library)!!!?

Comment: I mean, your original question was titled "point*er* cloud library" and tagged "printer-control-language"

Comment: When you are working with a pointer to cloud, it's already "shared". Just call the PCD writing function after the grabber is stopped, passing dereferenced pointer (I.e. `*cloud`)

Comment: @taketwo : Thanks for your answer, But what I was meant was that I want to save the cloud while the grabber is grabbing and not after that. I want to filter or do some segmentation live with Kinect. After the grabber stops then there's no frames anymore. Kinect is V2 by the way.

Comment: Ok, then call the writing function inside the `if (cloud) {...` clause, right after you add it to the visualizer. Also, I would suggest calling `cloud.reset()` after you are done writing so that in the next iteration of the `while` loop you don't save the same cloud again.